# Find size of shared memory tmpfs

Tags: tmpfs, ramdisk

When mounting a `tmpfs` we can pass as an option its (maximum) size and prevent the relevant fs from growing indefinitely and thus consuming all of our RAM, e.g.

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/shmemory
$ sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G noname /tmp/shmemory/

$ mount | grep -i shmem
noname on /tmp/shmemory type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1048576k)
```

However I do not see any size option in the `/dev/shmem` `tmpfs` dir that is present on my machine (and in most modern linux distributions)

```
$ mount | grep -iE "shm\s"
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
```

Does this mean the above can grow without any limit whatsoever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mount` never shows the size of filesystem.

Use `df` instead:

```
df /tmp/shmemory
```

That will show you desired information.

Comment: I accepted your answer as the `df` command __does__ show the size of the particular fs. However I am still wondering why in the `tmpfs` I created manually the size is given via the `mount` command while in `/dev/shm` is not;